# Uncaught ArgumentCountError em construtor

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, funções, argumento

Estou tentando listar os dados do banco, só que quando eu tento listar ele retorna o erro:

> Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function
>   processa::__construct(), 0 passed in

Quando eu declaro as variáveis no `$mostra = new processa(*);` ele me retorna o seguinte erro:

> Undefined variable: nome in

#### Meu código do index:

```
<div class="container">

    <?php $mostra = new processa($nome, $email, $telefone); 
    $mostra->listaru($conn); 
    if (!empty($mostra)): ?>

        <table class="table">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr align="center">
                    <th scope="col">Nome</th>
                    <th scope="col">Email</th>
                    <th scope="col">Telefone</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php while ($row = $mostra->fetch_assoc()): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <?= $row['nome'] ?>
                         </td>
                        <td>
                            <?= $row['email'] ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?= $row['telefone'] ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

#### classes.php:

```
class processa {
    private $nome, $email, $telefone;

    public function __construct($nome, $email, $telefone) {
        $this->nome = $nome;
        $this->telefone = $telefone;
        $this->email = $email;
    }
}

class processa {
    private $nome, $email, $telefone;

    public function __construct($nome, $email, $telefone) {
        $this->nome = $nome;
        $this->telefone = $telefone;
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public function listaru($conn) {

        $puxar = "SELECT * FROM usuario;";

        return $conn->query($puxar);
    }
}
```

Ele chega a mostrar a `<thead>` da tabela, só não mostra o conteúdo do `<tbody>`.

Comment: em `Processa` vc é obrigado a informar os três argumentos no construtor.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 4):

A mensagem de erro já diz qual é o problema, você cria um construtor com 3 parâmetros:

```
public function __construct($nome, $email, $telefone) {
```

E o chama com zero argumentos:

```
$user = new processa();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Function/ConstructorCall.php).

Se a função foi criada com 3 precisa chamar com 3.

Na verdade eu vejo outros problemas no código, embora ele funcione. Minha recomendação seria não fazer OOP até entender bem o que é isso. OOP sem entendimento só piora o código, como é o caso. Uma classe é desnecessária, a outra é simples demais para ser uma classe, e mesmo que insista nisso, o nome mostra que ela não é útil ou o que deveria ser.