# POO em PHP classes ( reutilizar metodos e atributos de outras classes herdadas)

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho 3 classes que possuem a mesma função, entretanto, algumas funções  tem o conteúdo da implementação diferente uma das outras: Ex:

```
class CategoryServices {

    /**
     * @var CategoryRepository
     */
    protected $repository;

    /**
     * @var CategoryRepository
     */
    protected $validator;

    /**
     * OwnersController constructor.
     *
     * @param CategoryRepository $repository
     * @param CategoryRepository $validator
     */
    public function __construct(CategoryRepository $repository, CategoryValidator $validator)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
        $this->validator  = $validator;
    }

    /**
     * Recuperar todos os registros ativos
     *
     * @return array $array
     */
    public function all() {

        try {

            $data = $this->repository->findWhere([ 'status' => 1 ])->all();

            // retorna resultado da gravacao
            return [
                'success'   => true,
                'message'   => null,
                'total'     => count($data),
                'data'      => $data,
            ];

        } catch (ValidatorException $e) {
            // retorna msg de erro
            return [
                'success'   => false,
                'message'   => $e->getMessageBag(),
                'total'     => null,
                'data'      => null,
            ];
        }
    }
```

```
class EquipmentServices {

    /**
     * @var CategoryRepository
     */
    protected $repository;

    /**
     * @var CategoryRepository
     */
    protected $validator;

    /**
     * OwnersController constructor.
     *
     * @param CategoryRepository $repository
     * @param CategoryRepository $validator
     */
    public function __construct(EquipmentRepository $repository, EquipmentValidator $validator)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
        $this->validator  = $validator;
    }

    /**
     * Recuperar todos os registros ativos
     *
     * @return array $array
     */
    public function all() {

        try {

            $data = $this->repository->findWhere([ 'status' => 1 ])->all();

            // retorna resultado da gravacao
            return [
                'success'   => true,
                'message'   => null,
                'total'     => count($data),
                'data'      => $data,
            ];

        } catch (ValidatorException $e) {
            // retorna msg de erro
            return [
                'success'   => false,
                'message'   => $e->getMessageBag(),
                'total'     => null,
                'data'      => null,
            ];
        }
    }
```

```
class EventServices {

    /**
     * @var CategoryRepository
     */
    protected $repository;

    /**
     * @var CategoryRepository
     */
    protected $validator;

    /**
     * OwnersController constructor.
     *
     * @param CategoryRepository $repository
     * @param CategoryRepository $validator
     */
    public function __construct(EventRepository $repository, EventValidator $validator)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
        $this->validator  = $validator;
    }

    /**
     * Recuperar todos os registros ativos
     *
     * @return array $array
     */
    public function all() {

        try {

            $data = $this->repository->findWhere([ 'status' => null ])->all();

            // retorna resultado da gravacao
            return [
                'success'   => true,
                'message'   => null,
                'total'     => count($data),
                'data'      => $data,
            ];

        } catch (ValidatorException $e) {
            // retorna msg de erro
            return [
                'success'   => false,
                'message'   => $e->getMessageBag(),
                'total'     => null,
                'data'      => null,
            ];
        }
    }
```

Ideia: 
Realizar a heranca de uma classe principal com todos os métodos que preciso, entretanto para cada classe, eu iria fazer um override na(s) função justamente para adequar a mesma na utilização da classe.

É possível fazer este procedimento? 
OBS: As classe possuem parametros diferentes no construtor, vejam.

Comment: "eu iria fazer um override", e isso seria diferente do que você já fez agora?

Comment: Isso responde? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/307092/101. E/ou isto? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45297/101. Essa deve matar de vez: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/247363/101. Isso deve ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/354826/101. Aqui dá uma informação importante: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/174414/101. Juntanto tudo acho que pode ser duplicata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma forma seria implementar o método de forma genérica em uma *trait*:

```
trait FindAll
{
    public function findAllWhere($where)
    {
        try {
            $data = $this->repository->findWhere($where)->all();

            return [
                'success'   => true,
                'message'   => null,
                'total'     => count($data),
                'data'      => $data,
            ];

        } catch (ValidatorException $e) {
            return [
                'success'   => false,
                'message'   => $e->getMessageBag(),
                'total'     => null,
                'data'      => null,
            ];
        }
    }
}
```

E nas suas classes utilizar a *trait* e definir os métodos `all` especializando o método `findAllWhere`:

```
class CategoryServices {

    use FindAll;    

    // ...

    public function all() {
        return $this->findAllWhere(['status' => 1]);
    }
}
```